# Create constructors for this VendingMachine class

Tags: java, constructor

**This is the last part I don't understand**

So far, the VendingMachine class does not have any constructors. Instances of a class with no constructor are always constructed with all instance variables set to zero (or null if they are object references). It is always a good idea to provide an explicit constructor.

Provide two constructors for the VendingMachine class:

1)  A default constructor that initializes the vending machine with 10 soda cans

2)  A constructor, VendingMachine(int cans), that initializes the vending machine with the given number of cans
Both constructors should initialize the token count to 0.

**This program lab is from:**

2.1. In this lab, you will implement a vending machine that holds cans of soda. To buy a can of soda, the customer needs to insert a token into the machine. When the token is inserted, a can drops from the can reservoir into the product delivery slot. The vending machine can be filled with more cans. The goal is to determine how many cans and tokens are in the machine at any given time.

What methods would you supply for a VendingMachine class? Describe them informally.

2.2.  Now translate those informal descriptions into Java method signatures, such as

```
public void fillUp(int cans)
```

Give the names, parameters, and return types of the methods. Do not implement them yet.

2.3.  What instance variables do the methods need to do their work? Hint: You need to track the number of cans and tokens.
Declare them with their type and access modifier.

2.4. Consider what happens when a user inserts a token into the vending machine. The number of tokens is increased, and the number of cans is decreased. Implement a method:

```
public void insertToken() 
{
   // Instructions for updating the token and can counts
}
```

You need to use the instance variables that you defined in the previous step.
Do not worry about the case where there are no more cans in the vending machine. You will learn how to program a decision "if can count is > 0" later in this course. For now, assume that the insertToken method will not be called if the vending machine is empty.

2.5.  Now implement a method `fillUp(int cans) 
to add more cans to the machine. Simply add the number of new cans to the can count.

2.6.  Next, implement two methods, getCanCount and getTokenCount, that return the current values of the can and token counts. (You may want to look at the getBalance method of the BankAccount class for guidance.)

2.7. You have implemented all methods of the VendingMachine class.
Put them together into a class, like this:

```
public class VendingMachine 
{
    private your first instance variable
    private your second instance variable 
    public your first method
    public your second method
    . . .
}
```

2.8  Now complete the following tester program so that it exercises all of the methods of your class.

```
public class VendingMachineTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      VendingMachine machine = new VendingMachine();
      machine.fillUp(10); // Fill up with ten cans
      machine.insertToken();
      machine.insertToken();
      System.out.print("Token count: ");
      System.out.println(machine.getTokenCount());
      System.out.println("Expected: . . .");
      System.out.print("Can count: ");
      System.out.println(machine.getCanCount()); 
      System.out.println("Expected: . . .");
   } 
}
```

Comment: "Instances of a class with no constructor are always constructed with all instance variables set to zero" - that's incorrect to start with, as fields can have field initializers... I'm slightly worried about the quality of the textbook (or whatever) that you're using :(

Comment: Don't agree with the "too broad votes". He shows the whole lab, and says the specific part he doesn't understand is how to make two constructors, one which takes an argument and one which uses a default value. There is nothing too broad about that.

Comment: The problem is that there is so much of the lab posted here that is irrelevant to the underlying question.  If those bits were removed and the relevant bits were all that were left, it would be a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link for documentation about constructors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

A constructor is simply a method that is always the first thing called when you create your object. Therefore variable initialization is often done in the constructor.

In your case, it should look something like this:

```
public class VendingMachine 
{
    //replace this with whatever variable name you used for the number of cans
    private int numCans;

    //the default constructor
    public VendingMachine() {

        //call the other constructor with the default value, 10
        this(10);
    }

    //the constructor which takes an argument
    VendingMachine(int cans) {

        //set the number of cans equal to the passed argument
        numCans = cans;
    }

    //insert all other methods and fields you already wrote for this class
}
```

Comment: IMO it would be better to make the parameterless method chain to the parameterized one, to reduce the code duplication. It's not so important with this simple example, but it's a good habit to get into. If there's one canonical constructor that all other constructors chain to, that makes it easier to prove that everything is initialized properly.

Comment: But, how do I make both constructors initialize the token count to 0?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right of course. I will edit my example to show that.

Comment: @AysanSarai simply set the variable to 0. For example, if your variable was named `tokenCount`, in the constructor you would write `tokenCount = 0;`. Please remember to upvote and accept this answer if it was helpful.